# Linux kernel 4.19.82 - Virtual Kernel Memory Layout - .text, .init, .data, .bss - unable to set the addresses

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I am working on custom made embedded board. Its currently running 3.10 kernel

I am trying to upgrade from 3.10 to 4.19.

So based on the kernel config options in 3.10, I am enabling/ disabling default kernel options in 4.19.

While doing that, I must have messed up something as I am getting this:

```
[    0.000000] Memory: 433580K/458752K available (4837K kernel code, 307K rwdata, 1136K rodata, 348K init, 165K bss, 25172K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0x9c800000 - 0xff800000   (1584 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0x9c000000   ( 448 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   (4839 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   ( 348 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   ( 308 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0x(ptrval) - 0x(ptrval)   ( 166 kB)
```

I want to understand which kernel config option is responsible to set those addresses ?

how should I debug this ? 
Any pointers / starting point would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are there, they're just not printed.  Linux has updated the print functions to not expose kernel addresses.  See [the "Plain Pointers" section](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html#plain-pointers) in the kernel `printk` documentation:

> The kernel will print `(ptrval)` until it gathers enough entropy.

This can be disabled with [the `debug_boot_weak_hash` kernel boot parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html), but you’ll still get a hash, not the real pointer value.

Comment: is there any way to get the real pointer value ?

Comment: just casting it to unsigned int, gives you the real value...